# Are the Gulfstream III's ailerons controlled by hydraulically boosted cables?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems, aircraft-maintenance, ailerons, gulfstream

Are the ailerons for a Gulfstream III controlled cables with hydraulic boost? Also, is it possible that an aircraft mechanic could easily access the control to tamper with it?

Comment: I assume this is for your novel research. Note I think taking out the hydraulics would disable the tail & rudder (both not visible from the cockpit) so not fixable in your story. And weakening the mechanical cable to the ailerons might only disable the mechanical backup, so wouldn't be a credible sabotage.

Comment: @Andy, if just the ailerons cable (not the hydrologics) was tampered with that wouldn't affect the tail or rudder would it?

Comment: @Robert some mechanical details [here](http://code7700.com/g450_aileron.html) might help. Maybe there's a crucial linkage he could snip somewhere (I really hope this **is** just for a work of fiction!)

Comment: At some point you might want to just hand-wave the details.  You're writing a novel, not a handbook on how to commit sabotage.  The few G-III mechanics that notice the inaccuracy will no doubt appreciate that you're not providing an instruction manual for bad guys.

Comment: @Andy I'd like to think anyone in a position to commit such a crime would already have the knowledge without Aviation.SE.

Comment: @Andy - Yes! - It's a science fiction novel. I want to make that very clear! See my blog https://novelwrites.com/my-books/ I think I am just going to go with a snipped cable and my alien controlling the failed aileron to save everybody. Dan is right - I really don't need in-depth detail - I just don't want to make something up that would look really silly for anyone with some knowledge of how a plane works...Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Just a tip if you're new to Stack Exchange.  We do things differently around here compared to say Quora or Reddit.  We only deal in concrete questions which can be answered with concrete, factual answers. "Questions" discussing proposals, speculating, seeking opinions etc are off topic.  If you phrase your questions carefully, you can get the answers you need but best to avoid aliens and telekinesis, as you have done here.

Comment: I hope you haven't put yourself on an NSA watchlist :0

Comment: @Simon - I think I have chosen a poor way to conduct research for my science fiction novel - I didn't know it was going to get so complicated. I just wanted to write a plausible scene that makes my character a hero...sigh...thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: @TomMcW I don't understand your comment - I don't really know what that would mean. I'm writing a science fiction action adventure book. Why would I be on a watch list for doing internet research when I am a writer?

Comment: @ngolden I'm just being facetious. Ever since Snowden spoke up I figure every time you you type words like "sabotage" and "airplane" in the same sentence it gets flagged for an analyst. Rarely are my comments to be taken seriously. Especially if there's an emoticon :)

Comment: @TomMcW Someone else in a previous comment alluded to that too so I was starting to wonder why...thanks for clarifying that you were teasing! I haven't seen Snowden but I just googled it and got your gist. Hopefully this book will be a bestseller and turned into a Hollywood screenplay and you'll get to see it at the movies :) I do plan on crediting the folks on S.E. in the acknowledgments. I am working hard to make the story enjoyable by at least showing the science is plausible. The fusion drive with an anti-proton energy source for interstellar space travel was a lot harder to research!

Comment: @ngolden I'm not sure that a cut aileron cable (even on a Gulfstream) is a scenario that requires outside help to safely land the aircraft. A pilot may be able to keep wings level with rudder.

Comment: Scary question are popping up lately, a few days ago was the guy who wanted to know it all about fire and fire detectors... :-/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the flight control surfaces on the Gulf Stream III are moved by cables with hydraulic assistance.

From a [study guide for the type](http://www.airplanedriver.net/study/g3_dc.htm).

> The flight controls on the G III are cable driven with hydraulic boost..  They are powered by both the "Combined" and "Flight" hydraulic systems.  Each of the systems provides 1500 psi to the flight control servo actuators.  When the landing gear or flaps are extended, the combined system pressure increases to 3,000 psi.  If one system fails, the remaining system pressure increases to 3000 psi.  Failure of one hydraulic system therefore, does not result in a loss of control effectiveness.

As to whether a mechanic could interfere with the controls, of course.  But for what purpose?  I am not sure that I understand what you mean by "tamper" but I assume that you mean sabotage. If so, then there are multiple ways to do this but I see no point in speculating as to what someone might do or why.

Comment: Re: for what purpose. According to OPs other question, they are writing a novel and want credible sabotage ideas. http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31686/plausible-scenario-for-aircraft-sabotage-for-a-science-fiction-novel

Comment: @Robert Thanks.  I'll stay clear of the motivations :)

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz I really wish I never asked this question because people keep finding it concerning. Hopefully my science fiction novel that I am almost finished with will be picked up by a traditional publisher and you will be able to read how there was a problem with an airplane's aileron but one of my main characters (an alien from Kepler 186f) saves the day...please read my previous comments - thanks!